# Deconvolving while suppressing other known signals

Tags: filters, noise, deconvolution, matched-filter, wiener-filter

Given a known impulse response $h(t)$ and an observed signal $y(t)=(h*x)(t)+n(t)$, my aim is to recover an estimate of $x(t)$ in the presence of unknown additive noise $n(t)$.

If the mean power spectral density of $n(t)$ is known as a function of frequency, [Wiener deconvolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_deconvolution) is a simple and elegant solution to this problem.

However if I additionally know that the noise is likely to contain (as additive components) specific other known signals which I want to suppress explicitly (to the extent that they appear) in favor of $h(t)$, is there a way to make use of this knowledge? [Wiener deconvolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_deconvolution) considers the magnitude of the transform of $n(t)$ but ignores phase information. Is there perhaps a more general approach that would allow me to suppress particular signals in the noise (while deconvolving for $h(t)$)?

Comment: The assumption of the Wiener filter is any noise which is independent of the signal with known spectrum (Not known function, as then this becomes a realization question and not an estimation in the mean question). If you defined the noise more clearly we might be able to build such solution.